# How often should I run dbms_stat for index in oracle db

Tags: oracle

I have a table that contains at least 100 million records and I have `index_1` for this table.

There is a job to insert / update / delete records to this table twice a day (around 100 thousand records in the morning and 1 million records in the afternoon).

My question is , should i do exec `dbms_stats.gather_index_stats` for `index_1` each time (twice a day) after the job finish to run ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're worried about this particular index?  Usually when people worry about statistics they worry about both table and index statistics.

Comment: Index maintenance is kind of expensive. If you are loading million rows, perhaps it would be faster if you drop the index before loading (so that insert would be fast) and create it afterwards. I don't know whether it'll be better or worse than what you are doing now, but - test it and see how it behaves.